# Start Solr cloud on Docker Swarm (1.12) without Zookeeper

Tags: docker, solr, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I am running Docker Swarm 1.12 on 3 CoreOS machines via Vagrant.

What is the best way to start a Solr cloud on the cluster?
Do I need Zookeeper?

I have gotten as far as this:

```
docker service create --mode=global --name solr -p 8983:8983 solr:5.3.1 bash -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -c"
```

But then the Cloud is empty because it does not know about the other 2 machines, how can I use Swarm's power here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Documentation

The [container image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/) describes how interconnect Zookeeper as a backing store for a distributed Solr setup:

> You can also run a distributed Solr configuration, with Solr nodes in
>   separate containers, sharing a single ZooKeeper server:
>
> Run ZooKeeper, and define a name so we can link to it:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --name zookeeper -d -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 jplock/zookeeper
> ```
>
> Run two Solr nodes, linked to the zookeeper container:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --name solr1 --link zookeeper:ZK -d -p 8983:8983 \
>       solr \
>       bash -c '/opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -z $ZK_PORT_2181_TCP_ADDR:$ZK_PORT_2181_TCP_PORT'
>
> $ docker run --name solr2 --link zookeeper:ZK -d -p 8984:8983 \
>       solr \
>       bash -c '/opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -z $ZK_PORT_2181_TCP_ADDR:$ZK_PORT_2181_TCP_PORT'
> ```

## Running distributed Solr on Docker Swarm

Starting with a 3 node swarm:

```
$ docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
2wkpmybf4wni8wia1s46lm2ml *  node1     Ready   Active        Leader
ajrnf5oibgm7b12ayy0hg5i32    node3     Ready   Active        
bbe8n1hybhruhhrhmswn7fjmd    node2     Ready   Active
```

Create a network

```
$ docker network create --driver overlay my-net
```

Start a zookeeper service and wait for it to start

```
$ docker service create --name zookeeper --replicas 1 --network my-net jplock/zookeeper
```

Start 2 solr instances configured to connect to the DNS address "zookeeper". For more information on swarm mode networking you can read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/)

```
$ docker service create --name solr --replicas 2 --network my-net -p 8983:8983 \
   solr \
   bash -c '/opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -z zookeeper:2181'
```

The web UI will be available on any node in the cluster

```
http://192.168.99.100:8983/
http://192.168.99.101:8983/
http://192.168.99.102:8983/
```

If you check the services you'll notice the containers are spread across all 3 nodes in the cluster. This is the default scheduling behaviour

```
$ docker service ps zookeeper
ID                         NAME         IMAGE             NODE   DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE          ERROR
3fhipbsd4jdazmx8d7zum0ohp  zookeeper.1  jplock/zookeeper  node1  Running        Running 7 minutes ago  

$ docker service ps solr
ID                         NAME    IMAGE  NODE   DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR
bikggwpyz5q6vdxrpqwevlwsr  solr.1  solr   node2  Running        Running 43 seconds ago  
cutbmjsmcxrmi1ld75eox0s9m  solr.2  solr   node3  Running        Running 43 seconds ago
```

Comment: Are you considering that this is run on Docker 1.12 Swarm? Where you use "docker service create ..." 
Could your example start 2 solr containers on the same machine? - We don't want that.

Comment: @viktorsmari I have updated my answer. To run this on Swarm you need to start 2 services and Swarm will by default spread the containers across the available nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted the Solr and Zookeeper on all of the machines so I used the `--mode=global` instead of `--replicas 2`

Comment: using this approach, the solr cloud nodes are registered with their VIP address at zookeeper. Is it possible to use the public ip / hostname of the swarm node for this? Like using the "-h" parameter in solr startup script? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @sebhaub Why is this important? Each Solr node is talking to zookeeper on a private network. Have you considered what would happen if more than one solr node was running on a host?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: I want to retrieve the shardUrls for a specific collection from zookeeper and then stream directly from that replica (given the shardURL). When using this approach, the shardUrl will contain the private VIP and a client is not able to connect then.  When starting with "docker run" on each node, i manually set the hostname using "solr start -f -h {hostname} ...". is there any chance to achieve what i want to do with swarm mode?